# Show Spin Buttons in for Number Input in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input

In all browsers we get spin button for input type Number except IE, is there any CSS or JS way we can get that in IE?

Chrome:

[image]

FireFox :

[image]

Opera:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

IE 11:

[image]

Comment: You can create a functionality with javascript by adding 2 buttons with arrows, but I think that's not what you are looking for. And you can use some javascript /jquery plugin